# Batch script extract contents between two strings

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to write this Batch script to extract the two parameters from an XML file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--<var name="SqlConnection" value="data source=SERVERNAME;initialcatalog=DB_NAME;user id=JackDaniels;password=G235X" />-->
<var name="SqlConnection" value="data source=SERVERNAME;initial catalog=DB_Name;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
```

My objective is to extract SERVERNAME and DB_NAME from the line that is not commented out.

So far my code looks like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
set "connectionString="
set result=""
set "INPUT_FILE=DBConnection.config"
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=<var eol=!" %%x in (%INPUT_FILE%) DO (
    ECHO %%x
)
PAUSE
```

I'm just not sure how to get everything right after "data source=" and "initial catalog=". Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: The answer to your question is: No. **`;)`**

Comment: The easier way is to use a scripting language that has the capability to read XML files in their pure format.  VBscript, Jscript and Powershell all have this capability.

Comment: @Squashman Thank you! I decided to write a Poweshell script that does the job using Regex. I posted the code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since many of you suggested that Batch is not an adequate way of doing this, I decided to play around with PowerShell, and was able to accomplish what I wanted with just a few lines, and some Regex!

```
$configPath = $PSScriptRoot + "DBConnection.config"
[xml]$XmlDocument = Get-Content -Path $configPath
$dataSource = $XmlDocument.var.Attributes[1].Value.ToString() # Extract the uncommented line, and the second attribute "value"

$serverName = ($dataSource -split 'data source=([^;]*);')[1] 
$db_name = ($dataSource -split 'initial catalog=([^;]*);')[1] 
$user_id = ($dataSource -split 'id=([^;]*);')[1]
$user_pass = ($dataSource -split 'password=([^;]*)')[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

The adequate way to extract this data is not via a Batch file, but with the methods suggested in a comment. However, the Batch file below perform this extraction in a relatively simple way:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem From the line that have "<var" followed by "value"...
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr "\<var.*value" input.txt') do (
   rem ... process the parts separated by space or equal sign, excepting if enclosed in quotes...
   for %%b in (%%a) do (
      rem ... and store the part after "value" variable
      if "!var!" equ "value" set "value=%%~b"
      set "var=%%~b"
   )
)

rem Separate "value" string at semicolons and assign each part via SET command
for %%a in ("%value:;=" "%") do set %%a

rem Show results:
echo data source=%data source%
echo initial catalog=%initial catalog%
echo Integrated Security=%Integrated Security%
```

Output example:

```
data source=SERVERNAME
initial catalog=DB_Name
Integrated Security=SSPI
```

Of course, if the data format described in the code changes, the program will fail...

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q42420941.txt"
FOR %%v IN (initial catalog data source initial_catalog data_source) DO SET "%%v="
FOR /f "delims=<>" %%z IN ('findstr /B /L /C:"\<var name" "%filename1%"') DO (
 FOR %%y IN (%%z) DO (
  FOR %%a IN (%%~y) DO (
   SET "alive=Y"
   FOR %%m IN (initial catalog data source) DO IF /i "%%a"=="%%m" SET "alive="&set %%a=Y
   IF DEFINED alive (
    IF DEFINED initial IF DEFINED catalog SET "initial_catalog=%%a"
    IF DEFINED data    IF DEFINED source  SET "data_source=%%a"
   )
   IF DEFINED catalog IF NOT DEFINED initial SET alive=y
   IF DEFINED source  IF NOT DEFINED data    SET alive=y
   IF DEFINED alive   FOR %%v IN (initial catalog data source) DO set "%%v="
  )
 )
)

ECHO %initial_catalog% and %data_source%

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q42420941.txt` containing your data for my testing.

first, clear out the variable-names.

next, parse each line that passes the `findstr` which is looking for lines that `/L` literally `/B` begin with the `/c:` character-sequence "< escaped by `\`) and take the first token delimited by `>` or `<`.

This neatly strips the awkward `<>` from the string and assigns the contents of the selected line to `%%z`

Next, use a simple `for` to present each token in the line to `%%y`.

Then with the quotes stripped off of `%%y` assign each token to `%%a`.

Search for a match against the keywords, and `set` the variable of the same name if found. Clear `alive` if a keyword is found.

If the string in `%%a` is not one of the keywords, then check to see whether `initial` and `catalog` are both set. If so, this is the required string, so assign it.

if `catalog` is found but not `initial` then mark as `alive`

If `alive` is still set, then we can clear the flags and wait for the start of another sequence.

OK - it has its faults. It won't detect initial_catalog/data_source if either is one of the four keywords (unlikely) and it assumes that the wanted data is the token following the two keywords - the `=` becomes a separator in the `for` list.